# Non-vanishing of sub gradient near optimal solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Consider the non-smooth optimization problem
  \begin{equation}   
      \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}    f(x).
\end{equation}
To solve the above problem, I am suing subgradient descent
\begin{equation}   
       x_{t+1} = x_t - \eta\partial f(x_t)
\end{equation}

My question is: why subgradient $\partial f(x)$ is non-vanishing in the nbd of the optimal solution if learning rate $\eta$ is fixed?

Comment: I think it's helpful to imagine what subgradient descent does if $ f $ is the absolute value function. With a fixed step size, we eventually end up bouncing left and right around the origin, never making further progress.

Comment: Why would you expect it to vanish ? What is your $f$ ? I'm afraid there maybe better ways to go about solving your problem, but for this I need more info about $f$.

Comment: @dohmatob, For convergence, we expect it to vanish like gradient in GD like algorithm. I agreed that there might be some other way to solve above problem. I asked this question from the theory of sub gradient point of view and no particular problem.

Comment: This makes no sense. Consider the abolute-value function $f: x \mapsto |x|$. A simple calculation reveals that $\partial f(x) = sign(x)$ if $x \ne 0$ and $\partial f(0) = [-1, 1]$. Also, we know (from pure algebraic considerations) that $f$ attains a global (and unique!) maximum of $0$ at the origin $0$. However, no amount of subgradient descent will take you there (provably!) as littleO already said. FYI, note that $0 \in \partial f(0)$.

Comment: In particular, $\partial f$ will never vanish no matter how close you come within $0$ without hitting it.

Comment: @dohmatob, you are supporting my question and proving it with an example. Can you give hint what condition on $\eta$ will lead to convergence of subgradient and why?

Comment: There is plenty of literature on subgradient methods, including step size rules that ensure convergence. I would suggest that Google is your friend here. But the other commenters are certainly correct, you do *not* get convergence of the subgradients, only of the objective value.

Comment: I would suggest @dohmatob convert his comment into an answer, and for the OP to accept it. It answers the question in total. If the OP has new questions he should possibly create a new question but I think a literature search is more appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Thx. I've done so.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. I general, you wouldn't expect the subgradient to vanish in the neighborhood of a minimum point $x^*$. All you can say is 0∈∂f($x^*$).

Indeed, consider the abolute-value function f:x↦|x|. A simple calculation reveals that ∂f(x)=sign(x) if x≠0 and ∂f(0)=[−1,1]. Also, we know (from purely algebraic considerations) that f attains a global minimum of 0 at the origin 0. However, no amount of subgradient descent will take you there (provably!) as @littleO already said. In particular, ∂f will never vanish no matter how close you come within 0 without hitting it.